# Vuetify 3 with Vue 3 : I don't know why my v-checkbox is invisible

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, vite

I work on a vue project with vite and I use vuetify to make it easier.
In a page, I use a checkbox in order to do something. My problem is that my checkbox is invisible even if I click on it. I know that my checkbox exists because I can see my label and when I click where there should be a checkbox, my function works.

In my project I import vuetify.min.css and vuetify.min.js like that:

```js
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js'
```

(I know my application has found these imports because when I change it by one letter, I get an error).

and this is my checkbox:
[image: marker checkbox]

```js
<div :style="{marginLeft: '20px'}">
      <v-checkbox
        v-model="checkPk"
        :label="$gettext('Markers')"
        color="primary"
        hide-details
/>
</div>
```

In my project, I use SCSS and I have a file vuetify.scss which is imported in my main.js.

In this file I try to add this:

```scss
.v-selection-control__input input{
  opacity: 1 !important;
  position: static !important;
  margin-right: 5px !important;
  // color doesn't work ???
  color: $primary !important;
}
```

after this, I have a checkbox like this:

[marker checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv8G2.png)

but I can't change its color and I don't know why.
(I know that `$primary` works for other components in my code)

I want a checkbox like this:
[image: marker checkbox]

`color: #B5E0D6`

Comment: Your screenshot shows a primary-colored checkbox with a label. It is not invisible. Did you mean to also color the label? Add `label="primary"` then ([see docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/checkboxes/))?

Comment: i edited my post to show what i have at first, it's invisible. But when i add what i show you, i see a checkbox but it isn't my primary color (i will edited my post to show you what i want), it's a color that i can't change even if i put `color: red`

Comment: Ah okay understood. I would remove the `position: static !important;` maybe you move it out of view with that. Do the [vue.js DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) show something unexpected?

Comment: Thanks to vuetify playground, I can test the vuetify doc. When I write `<v-checkbox color="red" label="test checkbox"></v-checkbox>` I see a red checkbox but when I put the same code in my project, I get the same blue one I sent and I can't change it.

Comment: if i remove `position: static !important`, i get this : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Pvm.png)  
and vue.js DevTools show nothing unexpected

Comment: Do you see your custom CSS file in the browser developer tools? Please compare to [Vuetify checkbox component docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/checkboxes/). I can see there that the selector `.v-selection-control__input i` would be responsible for the checkbox color. Alternatively just change `color="primary"` to `color="#B5E0D6"` to see the difference and check in your browser dev tools.

Comment: I see my custom CSS file in the browser developer tools, and the differences between mine and the class `.v-selection-control__input input` from vuetify.min.css are the opacity (witch is 0) and the position (witch is absolute).  
I try to remplace `$primary` by `#B5E0D6` but i see 0 difference

Comment: Vuetify uses [icon fonts](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts) to display checkboxes. It sounds like you are missing them. Can you check if they are installed and working?

Comment: Thank you is exactly that. i added   

```js
icons: {
    defaultSet: 'fa',
    aliases,
    sets: {
      fa,
      mdi,
    },
  },
```
In my function createVuetify (with aliases, fa and mdi imports)
and now it works !